# What are the cases where it'll be useful to compress already compressed data?

Tags: compression

As best as I understand, basic principle behind data compression is searching for repeated patterns and getting rid of the found duplicates, so the end result cannot be compressed any further without data loss, and if attempted anyway, will result in increase of the data size instead of desired reduction. But then there's, for example, ssh compression, which (when ssh is used as proxy) supposedly speeds up even already gzip-compressed and https-encrypted internet traffic. How and why it works (if it does)? Can a compressed file be compressed again without data loss via some magic? What are the use cases where it actually can happen and where it'd be useful?

Comment: Applying different compression algorithms can have good result. Usually no more than two. The method should not be similar in any mean. But applying the same type of compression results in low compression rate and even can result even in increase of size. Also speeding up the HTTPS encrypted traffic by compression makes sense, because HTTP encoding increase the size of message. Si first compress the HTTP encoded message, encrypt it with HTTPS and send.

Comment: So the ssh socks proxy thing is true then, the compression really does help with browsing? On <10Mbit networks, i mean, I imagine with speeds of 10mbit/s and more compression is just pointless

Comment: Yes, it helps. Many web servers does it. All browsers accept gzip and deflate compression. And probably on most HTTP servers it can be enabled. Browsers send Accept-Encoding but web servers respond with Content-Encoding, which is one or more from the ones sent by browser. It can be applied more than one single encoding. Any of them can be a type of compression.

Answer (score 1):

Generally only when the first compression reaches or at least approaches that compression format's maximum compression ratio. This would require *highly* redundant data as the uncompressed input. As you approach the maximum compression ratio, some redundancy remains in the compressed data.

A simple example is deflate, whose maximum compression ratio is 1032:1. If I start with a billion (10<sup>9</sup>) zero bytes, the first compression with gzip takes that down to 970501 bytes, a ratio of 1030.4:1. That result itself is mostly zeros, so a second compression gets it down to 2476 bytes, a ratio of 394.8:1. (I am subtracting the gzip headers and trailers to compute the ratio.) That is still redundant, though not with very long strings of zeros. It compresses a *third* time down to 298 bytes for a ratio of 8.78:1.

An attempt to compress a fourth time results in a larger output, as you would normally get when attempting to compress already compressed data. That's what happens most of the time, since normal compressed data is indistinguishable from random data to a compressor.

A second compression by ssh/sshd on already compressed data would almost never speed things up. It would only slow them down. Not just from the small expansion of the data, but from the time it takes to compress.

Comment: A special-purpose deflate compressor can get to a 1031.98:1 ratio on the first compression.

Comment: If ssh compression is pointless with https traffic, why then most VPN solutions include traffic compression option? Isn't it pointless, according to your answer?

Comment: It is pointless only if it is a second compression. If the traffic is not compressed, then it's a good thing. The penalty in space for already compressed traffic is small (a fraction of a percent), with really only a penalty in CPU time with no benefit.